# Get structure field by string in Goland

Tags: go, structure

In JS i can just:

```js
const str = "Name"
const obj = {"Name" : "SomeName"}
console.log(obj[str])
```

How i can do this in GoLand?

Comment: Easily doable by reflection, see [`Value.FieldByName()`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.FieldByName).

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you don't do this with structs in Go. When you need to be able to do this, the best way is usually to create a `map[string]string` first, which you can access the same way as in JS. Then you convert it into a struct with code like

```
structFromMap := myStructType{
 Name: myMap["Name"], 
 FavoritePokemon: myMap["FavoritePokemon"],
}
```

If you really need to interact with a struct this way, you can import the "reflect" package and then do

```golang
reflect.ValueOf(myStruct).FieldByName("Name")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    type user struct {
        firstName string
        lastName  string
    } // hire you define your struct

    u := user{firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"}
    s := reflect.ValueOf(u)

    fmt.Println("Name:", s.FieldByName("firstName"))
}
```

To help u started in Go I recommend this: https://quii.gitbook.io/learn-go-with-tests/

Have a good study/code :)

Answer (score 1):

kindly, You can use mapping in golang:

```
str:= "name"
obj := map[string]interface{}{
   "name": "someName",
}
fmt.printLn(obj[str])
```